# Django model multiple parameters in ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

So i have the following code:

```
class Team(models.Model):
   shortName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   fullName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Match(models.Model):
    team1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='team1')
    team2 = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='team2')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField('date start')


class Bet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

What i want is a parameter in Bet that pooints to team1 or team2 in Match, i have tried the following:

```
team = models.ForeignKey(Match.team1, Match.team2)
```

However that give me a syntax error. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration only indicates what type of object populates that attribute of the model. In this case, the foreign key points to `Team`, so the correct declaration should be

```
team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

On the other hand, listing the team twice seems inefficient, so you would do better to simply have a choice field for which team was selected in the bet. As one example:

```
team = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('H', 'Home team'), ('A', 'Away team')))
```

Then your view code would switch off of that and determine which of the two teams to show.